# Poisson regression on incidence rate data over time in R

Tags: r

I'm having a bit of trouble with the above (calculating poisson regression on incidence rate data over time in R). The rate outcome is per 100000 and I was wondering if it is appropriate to adjust for this as so `glm((Cancer_Incidence_Rate/100000)~time, family = poisson)` Thank you in advance for any information or explanation you can provide on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to divide the rate by a constant; in fact, this can lead to P-values and significance levels that are wrong. What you should do, if different observations represent different numbers of people/total exposures, is take into account the exposure. You can do this by either modelling your response as a rate per unit exposure, and using the exposure as a weight; *or* by using the (log-)exposure as an offset.

See [my post on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66791/where-does-the-offset-go-in-poisson-negative-binomial-regression/66878#66878) on the role of the offset in Poisson regression.

Comment: Thank you! So I need the numbers of the population that is being sampled it seem? (rate can't be analyzed alone?)

Comment: @Cenoc if you don't have the numbers that are being sampled, you'll be making the assumption that every observation accounts for 1 unit of exposure. This may be correct, but only you know your data....

Comment: that makes complete sense. So the offset would then be `log(100000/population)` since that would translate the rate to the number of cases - where `population` is the population exposed in every single year and `100000` is taking into account the incidence rate is per 100000 (person-year)

Comment: @cenoc I think you mean `log(population/100000)`.

Answer (score 0):

Poisson regression is a method which predicts positive integers. Is the data count data? If you want to predict the rate with poisson regression and you don't have integers, then you can round the rate:
`glm((round(Cancer_Incidence_Rate/100000))~time, family = poisson)`
Could you provide more information about the distribution of the data?

Comment: You _don't_ want to round the response if you're modelling a rate, even if `glm` complains.